# white space on the entire screen when i use frameset

Tags: html, space, frameset

I have a big white space filling almost half of the screen, this is the same error on every browser. Even when i click links it doesn't go away.
Here is the index file

```
<html>
<title>Terrapene.dk</title>
<frameset rows="*,*" cols="316" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="false">
    <frameset rows="72,89%">
      <frame name="hoved3" src="front.htm" target="_self" scrolling="no" noresize marginheight="5">
      <frameset cols="*,80%">
    <frame name="hoved5" src="bond.htm" target="_self" scrolling="auto" noresize>
        <frame name="hoved4" src="Velkommen/Velkommen.html" target="_self">
      </frameset>
    </frameset>
  <noframes> 
  <body bgcolor="#008000">
  </body>

  </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using framesets anyway? That's asking for problems.

Comment: Not my own site, editing for someone else, asked myself the same question, but why the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the following change to the outer `frameset` to address the white-space issue (note the change from wildcard (`*`) to 100% height):

`<frameset rows="100%,*" cols="316" framespacing="0" frameborder="0"  border="false">`

Here's a demo page on my server:

http://jackpattishalljr.com/stackoverflow/terrapene.html

Also, it probably wouldn't hurt to add the frameset doctype (although, this by itself, does not address the whitespace issue you found):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

P.S. Thanks for this ***BLAST FROM THE PAST*** with a frameset question ;)